# Seriously stuck on Ruby array reordering

Tags: ruby, arrays

I need to reorder an array based on dependent elements. If an element is an array (has dependency), the second element of that array is the dependency, and will be required to come before that array. All dependency information is then removed as we don't need any more, and we return an array with corrected order.

```
# array1 = [['a'], ['b','c'], ['c','a']]
# ordered = ['a', 'c', 'b']
# logic: c comes before b, a comes before c
```

Here is my approach which I think is over-engineered:

```
array1.each_with_index do |ar, i|
  # ignore elements without dependencies
  if ar.count > 1
    # get dependency
    dep = ar[1]

    # get index for element where this dependency is first
    dep_index = array1.index { |a| a.first == dep }

    # remove found dependency and store
    dep_element = array1.delete_at(dep_index)

    # insert found dependency to before current element
    array1.insert(i, dep_element)

    # delete processed dependency
    ar.delete(dep)
  end
end
```

The obvious problem with the above is that as I iterate through the array, elements which have dependencies I haven't processed will be shifted back, yet the loop will only be performed once. So, I introduced a `while`:

```
while array1.flatten.count > array1.count
```

However, my result is `['c', 'a', 'b']`.

I have also been tasked to test for self-referential and circular (infinite) dependency loops. Should I have used an Enumerator? Should have I converted array to different structure (objects) to enable easier management of order?

Comment: You have added too many non-technical sentences,only put the problem statement. it is too time consuming to read all your lines. tell us the algorithm based on which you wrote the code. In that case if we know the algorithm,we can provide you better solution.

Comment: Appears somebody has updated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out [TSort](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/tsort/rdoc/TSort.html), which comes with the Ruby standard library.

It performs a topological sort, which sounds like what you need. Using your example above:

```
require 'tsort'

class Hash
  include TSort
  alias tsort_each_node each_key
  def tsort_each_child(node, &block)
    fetch(node).each(&block)
  end
end

def deps arr
  arr.map { |head, *tail| {head => tail} }.reduce(&:merge).tsort
end

deps [['a'], ['b','c'], ['c','a']]
#=> ['a', 'c', 'b']
```

Comment: @boris-stitnicky That's a cool trick with Array.each! Thanks for the tip :)

Comment: Thanks for teaching me `TSort`, managed to overlook it in StdLib. That's it, Tarjan's algorithm.

Comment: Excellent solution! All I can hear in my head is 'RTFM'!

Answer (score 2):

No need to reinvent the wheel, use Rake:

```
require 'rake'

ary = [[:a], [:b, :c], [:c, :a]]

ordered = []
ary.each { |head, *tail| task head => tail do ordered << head end }
task( main: ary.map( &:first ) ).invoke

ordered
#=> [:a, :c, :b]
```

Otherwise, there is an algo for this, but I forgot its name.

Comment: Rake does have to deal with dependency ordering, so using this trick is clever.

Comment: @Zenph: Dear Zenph, let me tell you my sad story. I am a biologist, who, in the high school, was sitting next to a future therotetical physicist, and was better in math than him. But I was too good to go to study math and computer science, I went on to biology. And I was treated lika a lab monkey. Nobody expected anything intelligent of me. So I found a job in finance. I had no career progress for 4 years there and I left. That was 8 years ago. I had an opportunity to get a degree in bioinformatics, so I went for it, because I was confident in my brain.

Comment: But again, I was treated as an appliance-using monkey. I was told especially not to program, because "there are all kinds of snags there". At that time, I was very proficient MS Excel user, and I knew some crappy languages from childhood, such as Pascal, not to mention Basic. I didn't have a father in the field to tell me not to learn crappy macro languages and crappy user interfaces. The only non-crappy language I knew was Lisp, but only theoretically, because when I studided up the Lisp book as 14 years old, I had no machine to run it on.

Comment: Listen, I'm almost finished. So I spent 5 years of my doctoral study trying not to program and do patway simulation in MS Excel (later switched to Gnumeric after I ran away to GNU when I finally understood that Windows is for monkeys.), then in Octave (I didn't know http://abandonmatlab.wordpress.com/ blog yet), and then, finally, 2 years ago, after being stuck on everything, I told to myself that I'm too good to fail like this, and I did my research, and I learned Ruby, and I finally felt not like a monkey, but like a [master of the machine](https://github.com/boris-s/sy).

Comment: Though it's off-topic, @Zenph, if you don't know topological sort it doesn't mean you're "not ready for employment". There is a lot of room in the software industry for people of varying skills levels. Rather than entering competitions, I would suggest picking up some simple jobs on oDesk or a similar site, or writing programs which you personally want to write.

Comment: @RubyLovely: So here I am, 38 years old, a student expecting to graduate after 7 years of study, feeling like crap, and trying to get [John Woods's](http://github.com/mohawkjohn) NMatrix library work together with [the first Petri net simulator in Ruby](http://github.com/boris-s/y_petri) hat I know of that I wrote. No, I haven't found my way.

Comment: Sorry to hear that Boris! Least you have your skills and expertise. You cannot fall behind so long as you are improving those areas of your life. RE the job: I'm just going to say I reached out to the community for help in a particularly unique problem I'd not encountered. Hopefully that will show my resourcefulness and not lack of formal education.