# Using TSort in Ruby to reorder and sort arrays

Tags: arrays, ruby, algorithm, sorting

Hoping I can get some help on this particular reordering/sorting question in Ruby.

I've got an array of arrays, like so:

```
[['b', 'f'],
['f', 'h'],
['a', 'e'],
['b', 'c'],
['b', 'd'],
['e', 'g'],
['c', 'f'],
['d', 'f'],
['f', 'g'],
['g', 'h']]
```

The second element in each array must occur after the first, so I want to write a program that will sort them into an array that looks like this:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
```

I'm trying to use Ruby's built in `TSort` library, and I'm also working from [this stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16862843/seriously-stuck-on-ruby-array-reordering/16863069#16863069).

So I'm doing this:

```
class Hash
  include TSort
  alias tsort_each_node each_key
  def tsort_each_child(node, &block)
    fetch(node).each(&block)
  end
end

def flex_sort(arr)
  stuff = arr.map do |head, *tail|
    {head => tail}
  end
  stuff.reduce(&:merge).tsort.reverse
end

sorted = flex_sort(flex)
```

I have several questions about this. First, am I even on the right track? Second, when I run this code, you will notice that the initial array of arrays does not include an array with the first element `'h'`, so that when I convert them into a hash, and try to run `.tsort`, I get something like `key 'h' does not exist`, which forces me to put `['h']` into the array of arrays just so that it doesn't break. Is there a way around this?

Comment: It don't understand your question. It would be clearer if your example didn't sort the elements into alphabetical order. Are you assuming that the following will not occur: `[[a', 'b'], ['b', 'c'], ['c', 'a']]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`fetch`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-fetch) takes a second parameter which is the default value, if it doesn't exist.

```
fetch(node, []).each(&block)
```

the second problem is when you `&:merge` your array into each other, you're overwriting previous values. The current result of the merge is

```
{"b"=>["d"], "f"=>["g"], "a"=>["e"], "e"=>["g"], "c"=>["f"], "d"=>["f"], "g"=>["h"]}
```

with only the one value per key. If you change that to

```
def flex_sort(arr)
  stuff = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = [] }
  arr.each do |head, tail|
    stuff[head] << tail
  end

  stuff.tsort.reverse
end
```

your hash looks like

```
{"b"=>["f", "c", "d"], "f"=>["h", "g"], "a"=>["e"], "e"=>["g"], "c"=>["f"], "d"=>["f"], "g" =>["h"]}
```

and now running your `tsort` you end up with

```
["a", "e", "b", "d", "c", "f", "g", "h"]
```

which is extremely close to what you're wanting. Not familiar with this sort to know if there's a way to force it to pick some keys before others when there's a multiple possibilities. But this gets you that much closer, at least.

Comment: Ahh I see. This get's me most of the way there. Thanks!